# Remove line in csv python Panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
ID   Number
1123  222222222222222      
332        3333333333      
112         222222222
```

This is my csv , how to remove by `index` ?  or specific line ?

```
for i, produto in produtos.iterrows():
     del produto[2]
```

i try this one tu delete by index 2 `"332"`

Comment: Can you please provide the rest of your code? Do you import the csv and convert it to a dataframe? What output are you getting? More code would be helpful to try and ascertain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct except that instead of `producto[2]` use `producto[i]`

The full code is:

```
for i, produto in produtos.iterrows():
     del produto[i]
```

Comment: raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 1123

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1123, 332, 112], 'Number': [222222222222222, 3333333333, 222222222]}).set_index('ID')
df.drop(index=df.iloc[1, :].name, inplace=True) # by row number
# or 
# df.drop(index=df.loc[df['ID'] == 332].index, inplace=True) # by value
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               Number
ID                   
1123  222222222222222
112         222222222
```

Comment: KeyError: '[1] not found in axis'

Comment: same error KeyError: '[332] not found in axis'

Comment: Edited. See the last version